# Why are there "Tag Badges"?

Tags: support, badges

Sometimes when I come to a user profile page, I will see some "Tag Badges" like the [10.10 badge](https://askubuntu.com/badges/65/10-10), [the unity badge](https://askubuntu.com/badges/63/unity), and [the installation badge](https://askubuntu.com/badges/80/installation).  Not only these.

But I can't find "Tag Badges" on [this page](https://askubuntu.com/badges).  So how could they exist?

Comment: There's a subtab on the page you link btw:  http://askubuntu.com/badges?tab=tags

Comment: Never noticed that...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So how could they exist?

They don't. The Ubuntu fairy hand-embroiders them and leaves them under your pillow....when at least 20 of your answers to questions containing that tag have a combined score (upvotes) of over 100.

Comment: Over 100, and at least 20 answers.

Comment: suggest edit: "hand-embroiders" should read "forges"